# Data Tables second table is shown but no reaction

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have implemented a table from data tables 
Link [https://datatables.net/]

i would like to use two tables in one site with different columns and datas in the columns after the mysqli connection i insert the data sets with a while mysqli fetch array function the first table works properly
"urlaubstage" -> is correct

but table 2
no matter what i do even var_dump i dint not get any reaction but the table is display correctly on the page but with empty columns

This is the html code

```
            <table id="table_id" class="display">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Urlaubstage Jahr</th>
                        <th>Urlaubstage Anspruch</th>
                        <th>Urlaubstage Beansprucht</th>
                        <th>Urlaubstage Rest</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                        $urlaubsTage = $row[4];
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>{$urlaubsTage}</td>";
                        echo "<td>Anspruch</td>";
                        echo "<td>Beansprucht</td>";
                        echo "<td>Rest</td>";
                        echo "halllo";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
!!!!!!!!!!!!<p>HERE STARTS THE SECOND TABLE</p>!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            <table id="table_id2" class="display">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Urlaub Antragsdatum</th>
                        <th>Urlaub Startdatum</th>
                        <th>Urlaub Enddatum</th>
                        <th>Urlaubs Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                        var_dump($row); -> EVEn VAR_DUMP IS NOT SHOWN
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>Antragsdatum</td>";
                        echo "<td>Startdatum</td>";
                        echo "<td>Enddatum</td>";
                        echo "<td>Status</td>";
                        echo "halllo";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

JQUERY CODE
....

```
$('#table_id').DataTable();
//FUNKTION FÜR ZWEITE TABELLE
$('#table_id2').DataTable();
```

....

[Picture of Code and Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEH11.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got the answer by myself, after the first loop runs the query $sql with mysqli_fetch_array($sql) you cant use it anymore on the second loop why? cause it ran on the first loop and its over solution

rename;

$sql = mysqli_query(same query);
$sql2 = mysqli_query(same query);

first loop while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
second loop while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2);

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to execute the same query twice. You don't need the while loop either. Try to get the results into an array and then loop the array multiple times.

```
$result = $conn->query($sql)->fetch_all();
//...
foreach ($result as $row) {
    //...
}
// Repeat the same loop again without calling query again
//foreach...
```